# Zip file attached to http response downloaded in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httpresponse

I receive following headers in client

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers :Origin, Accept, X-Requested-Wi…Request-Headers, X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="2019-08-01_1564654615513.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
Date:Thu, 01 Aug 2019 10:17:04 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

It is enough for chrome to aoutomatically download my zip, for edge to open save dialog and then save file, but in firefox i have these headers with response but not any action. Do i need additional headers for firefox? Thanks.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/zip ` should be fine.

Comment: I'm sorry for style of my post, but i have this header applied, thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's why I think Firefox should be fine.

Comment: Is there some headers can force file downloading in firefox?

Comment: You already have `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...`. I don't see what could be wrong.

Comment: Can download be blocked by some thing like CORS policy as i testing my app on localhost?

Comment: check the browser call response.What is the response code for this request?

Comment: It is status 200

Comment: It is all the same like in edge or chrome, differ only that file is not downloaded in firefox (or not parsed from header)